# Matrix Factorization of Sums of Products

Tags: matrices, polynomials

Inspired by [David Eisenbud's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Eisenbud) *Matrix Factorization* [Numberphile video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wTUSz-HSaBg&t=613s), I try to factor sums of products of three variables:

$$s_k = a_1b_1c_1 + a_2b_2c_2 + a_3b_3c_3 +\, ... + a_kb_kc_k$$

A related [paper](https://pages.stolaf.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/46/2017/01/MFE1.pdf) of Crisler and Diveris demonstrates how to factor sums of products of two variables:

$$f_k = g_1h_1 + g_2h_2 + g_3h_3 +\, ... + g_kh_k$$

Their method is inductive:

In the case $k=1$, we have $f_1 = gh$ and $[g][h] = [gh] = [f_1]$ is a $1 \times 1$ factorization. Assume now that $A$ and $B$ are matrix factorizations of $f_{k-1}$, that $AB = If_{k-1}$. The following is a matrix factorization of $f_k$:

[image]

**Question:**

> How to factor a sum of three-factor products in terms of *Matrix Factorization*?

Comment: Please don't post unsearchable images of text.  Take the time to write it out (using *MathJax*).

Comment: My *MathJax* skills are still under development.